# Change appearance of a MONO application

Tags: themes, mono

I would like to theme an application that uses the mono framework. I have tried various GTK2/3 "solutions" but these haven't changed anything.

just two examples I've tried:

`env GTK_THEME="HighContrast" mono /path-to-app.exe`

`GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/HighContrast/gtk-2.0/gtkrc mono /path/to/app.exe`

In both scenarios, the app just opens as normal without change.

Comment: +1
Some mono apps (i.e. ROMVault) are broken on Dark Theme. Only switching the system theme works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I come from the future.

More recent builds of Mono now support GTK themes to some extent. But be warned: this is a double-edged sword, as the result is sometimes bad. See these GitHub issues:

- [Dark theme broken #20078](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/20078)
- [Mono application with dark GTK+ themes do not look good and no override available #9998](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/9998)

In short, Mono seems to detect your active GTK theme, and you can't easily tell it to use a specific theme.

If you want to try it out anyway, you need to [add the official Mono repository](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/) to get the latest changes, as distributions' repositories can be very outdated. At the time of writing in early 2023, Debian (and Ubuntu and all derivatives..) is still hosting version 6.8.0, originally released early 2020.

If you're already seeing a dark theme in Mono but want to **disable** it, use [this method](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/9998#issuecomment-1238748342):

```
GTK_DATA_PREFIX= mono <your_app>.exe
```

Comment: Thank you for all the research and compilation of info you've done about this (especially in [mono/mono#20078](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/20078)). It saved me a lot of time and headache, which instead I devoted to altering the code of the OSS program I wanted to fix the theme of.

Comment: My pleasure! <3